# How to find the number of Basic safety message in Omnet++ project?

Tags: omnet++, veins

I'm new to omnett++, veins. I'm making a VANET project, and I want to count the number of BSM (Basic safety messages) sent from vehicles to RSU.
Can anyone help

thank you

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Your question needs some work so the community can better help you. Take a look at [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and give it another try.

Answer (score 1):

For inspiration, you can check the [`DemoBaseApplLayer`](https://github.com/sommer/veins/blob/veins-5.0/src/veins/modules/application/ieee80211p/DemoBaseApplLayer.cc#L258), included with Veins 5.0, which uses OMNeT++'s `recordScalar` method to record the value of its `receivedBSMs` member.

For more details on result recording, I would recommend to take a look at the [OMNeT++ user's manual section on recording results](https://doc.omnetpp.org/omnetpp/manual/#sec:sim-lib:output-scalars) and try an interactive example such as the [OMNeT++ Tic Toc tutorial](https://docs.omnetpp.org/tutorials/tictoc/).